# why WebSocket rather than Socket?

Tags: sockets, websocket

Java Applets support socket but limits the connection towards the
http server from which the applet has been downloaded.

Why a WebSocket abstraction has been created for sending data
from Javascript/HTML 5 ? Wouldn't have been possible to add support
for a “classical” socket in JS and limit the connection (as it
has been done for Java Applets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because WebSocket starts as a HTTP request, therefore it is easier to go through firewalls and other inspectors. Also, such HTTP negotiation can do HTTP operations like sending/retrieving cookies from the browser for example, which provides a nice integration with the rest of the web application.